# Canada Post Rates Error in Ionic Project Response for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic3

I am working on an HTTP request which sends POST request to Canada Post API for querying the quotes of shipping:

```
getRates(weight: number, originPostal, destPostal) {
    const options = {
      headers: new HttpHeaders({
        'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(this.TEST_USERNAME + ':' + this.TEST_PASSWORD),
        'Accept': 'application/vnd.cpc.ship.rate-v3+xml',
        'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.cpc.ship.rate-v3+xml',
        'Accept-language': 'en-CA',
      }),
    };

    const body = `
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
      <mailing-scenario xmlns="http://www.canadapost.ca/ws/ship/rate-v3">
        <customer-number>${this.TEST_NUMBER}</customer-number>
        <parcel-characteristics>
        <weight>${weight}</weight>
        </parcel-characteristics>
        <origin-postal-code>${originPostal}</origin-postal-code>
        <destination>
          <domestic>
            <postal-code>${destPostal}</postal-code>
          </domestic>
        </destination>
      </mailing-scenario>
    `;

    return this.http.post<any>(this.TEST_URL, body, options)
}
```

The query works fine on Postman and not work on the Ionic project(`ionic serve` and `ionic run -l`). I searched online and it is a CORS issue[Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/22022), I have added below into `ionic.config.json` file

```
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/price",
      "proxyUrl": "https://ct.soa-gw.canadapost.ca/rs/ship/price"
    }
  ]
```

The API key, URL are provided by Canada Post which can be found [here](https://www.canadapost.ca/cpo/mc/business/productsservices/developers/services/fundamentals.jsf#TestValues)

Errors I have:

> Failed to load https://ct.soa-gw.canadapost.ca/rs/ship/price: Response
>   for preflight has invalid HTTP status code 500.

```
14:32:24.786 shipping.ts:34 {"headers":{"normalizedNames":{},"lazyUpdate":null,"headers":{}},"status":0,"statusText":"Unknown Error","url":null,"ok":false,"name":"HttpErrorResponse","message":"Http failure response for (unknown url): 0 Unknown Error","error":{"isTrusted":true}}
```

Any help would be appreciated!

**Update on June 15,2018:**

I have tried it on real device today, get such error:
[image]

[preflight response issue with ionic3 app on ios build only [ resolved ]](http://uncaughterror.com/programming/ionic3/preflight-response-issue-with-ionic3-app-on-ios-build-only-resolved/)
and [Ionic UIWebView](https://ionicframework.com/docs/wkwebview/), unfortunately, the request still get the same error...

Comment: You may want to add an extension to your browser for testing from local machine: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi

Comment: @DaleNguyen I tried it but no luck

Comment: Try it on your device. This might only be a browser issue.

Comment: @Ari  I have tried it on real IOS device, no luck...

Comment: @haifzhan: The chrome extension has helped me in the past, but I had a case that I was not able to make it work on the device. One way to go around this is to have a server that polls the API and stores the data. Then have your clients get the data from your server instead of directly getting it from the API.

Comment: Can you use following code in your server side API.
if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ORIGIN'])) {
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
            header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true');
            header('Access-Control-Max-Age: 86400');    // cache for 1 day
        }

Comment: if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'OPTIONS') {
            header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
            
            if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_METHOD']))
                header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, OPTIONS");

            if (isset($_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']))
                header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers:        {$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS']}");
            exit(0);
        }

I am using the same concept rest services. for my ionic app, Its in php you may use according to your server.

Comment: @SunilRawat Thanks for your suggestion, unfortunately I am using Canada Post public API, I am not able to work on server side. I have figured out the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
getRates(weight: number, originPostal, destPostal) {
    this.http.setDataSerializer('utf8');
    return this.http
      .post(
        this.URL,
        this.body(weight, originPostal, destPostal),
        this.headers(this.USER_NAME, this.PASSWORD)
      );
  }

  private headers(username, password) {
    return {
      'Authorization': 'Basic ' + btoa(username + ':' + password),
      'Accept': 'application/vnd.cpc.ship.rate-v3+xml',
      'Content-Type': 'application/vnd.cpc.ship.rate-v3+xml;',
      'Accept-language': 'en-CA'
    };
  }

  private body(weight, originPostal, destPostal) {
    return `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <mailing-scenario xmlns="http://www.canadapost.ca/ws/ship/rate-v3">
    <customer-number>MY_CUSTOMER_NUMBER</customer-number>
      <parcel-characteristics>
        <weight>${weight}</weight>
      </parcel-characteristics>
      <origin-postal-code>${originPostal}</origin-postal-code>
        <destination>
          <domestic>
            <postal-code>${destPostal}</postal-code>
          </domestic>
        </destination>
    </mailing-scenario>`;
  }
```

There's a couple of issues to make the request not work:

1. HttpClient module(Angular module) in ionic always have CORS, ionic team has related FAQ. In my case I use firebase as the backend, therefore not use http very often, I decided to switch to [Ionic Native Http](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/http/)
2. XML issue, there's a leading space before tag `<?xml>` which I didn't realize until print out the error message details(the error message itself was in XML as well, the rest omits, therefore at the beginning I thought it only has error message **Server**, once I cut the whole message into pieces and print it out on console, I find it was illegal xml format, then I figure out there's a leading space):
   [image: Error]

Convert XML to JSON(xml2js makes life easier):

```
import * as xml2js from 'xml2js';

this.rateProvider.getRates(this.totalWeight, this.ORIGINAL_POSTAL_CODE, this.selectedAddress.postalCode.toUpperCase())
  .then(resp => {
    xml2js.parseString(resp.data, (err, jsonResp) => {
      this.quotes = this.extractQuotes(jsonResp);
      this.presentActionSheet(this.quotes);
      this.isSelected = false;
    });
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
  });
```

Finally, get it work:
[image]